# nginx. Proxy subdomain to blogspot

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite, subdomain

I want to set up my nginx to proxy the  subdomain `http://blog.mydomain.com`to`http://myblog.blogspot.com`, but I don't want to rewrite the url. So the user will see mydomain.com url instead of the blogspot one.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://serverfault.com/q/587723/192672)

Answer (score 1):

You have my permission to do so.

Comment: C'mon! Please, how can I do it?