# Proxy to the same subdomain with nginx

Tags: nginx, domain, subdomain

I just bought the domain `xappspot.com`, and what I'd like to do is proxy request to it to `appspot.com`.

For example:

`http://json-time.xappspot.com/time.json` -> `http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json`

How could I configure nginx to do this? I searched for a while and can't find resouces to pass the subdomain. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The common way to configure such a thing in `nginx` is to use the [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive.

Something like :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name json-time.xappspot.com;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://json-time.appspot.com;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the subdomain is dynamic. I mean, it's not just `json-time`

Comment: @wong2 Ha ok. So can you update your question to me more clear about what you want to do ? thank you